# Extraction and summation of data in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I  have a following `logdata.txt` file which contains

```
07/05/2016 11:39  0.00167
07/05/2016 11:39  0.00333
07/05/2016 11:39  0.00167
07/05/2016 11:40  0.00333
07/05/2016 11:40  0.005
07/05/2016 11:40  0.00667
```

I have written a code which sums the third column and output is

```
07/05/2016 0.02167
```

This result is stored in `senddata.txt`

```
 f = open('logdata.txt','r+')

    res = OrderedDict()
    for line in f:
        values = line.split('')

        if len(values) == 4:
            date = values[0]
            val = values[3]
            if res.get(date):
                res[date] += int(val)            
            else:
                res[date] = int(val)

    f.close()


    f = open('senddata.txt', 'w')
    for line in res.keys():
        f.write('{} {}'.format(line, res[line]))
    f.close()
```

It is giving the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    res[date] = int(val)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.00167\n'
```

can any one help me to debug it...

Comment: Use splitlines instead of split.

Comment: you must delete `"\n"` from string so use `res[date] = res[data].strip()` and you should cast it to `float` not `int` so use `float(res[date])`

Comment: You should use `float(val)`.

Comment: not understanding sir

Comment: You can't use `int()` for a non whole number

Comment: `line.split('')` is not valid, it throws an error. You can't have an empty separator. Why didn't you copy paste your code directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `\n` which is the newline character and almost always appears at the end of a line when you iterate through a file line by line. I've shown how to fix it as well as how to improve other aspects of your code.

```
# Always use a with statement to open files, so it
# closes automatically even if something goes wrong
# You're not writing to the file so the default mode 'r' is fine
with open('logdata.txt') as logdata:
    res = OrderedDict()
    for line in logdata:

        # Passing no arguments splits on whitespace and removes empty strings
        # so the result is intuitive and there's no need to 'clean' it
        values = line.split()

        # Note that the length is now 3, not 4
        if len(values) == 3:

            # Tuple unpacking is sometimes much nicer than using an index
            # _ is the conventional way of saying 'a value I don't care about'
            date, _, val = values

            # Much nicer than an if statement
            # If .split() hadn't removed the whitespace the best thing to do
            # would be to remove it with val.strip() or val.rstrip()
            res[date] = res.get(date, 0) + float(val)

# Again, not the with statement
with open('senddata.txt', 'w') as f:

    # This is how to get both key and value at once
    # Even with your old method, 'for line in res:' is good enough
    # as iteration directly over a dict means over its keys 
    for line, value in res.items():
        f.write('{} {}'.format(line, value))
```

You may want to remove the `if len(values) == 3` because if that's not the case it may indicate invalid data that you want to fix instead of passing over it silently. In that case you can also just say `date, _, val = lines.split()`.

Getting more advanced, there's an even cleaner way to deal with the default starting value of 0. Usually you would use a `collections.defaultdict` but that's not an easy option if you already need an `OrderedDict`. So you can get the same functionality a little more manually:

```
class OrderedFloatDict(OrderedDict):

    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 0
...
res = OrderedFloatDict()
...
res[date] += float(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "\n" from the from the last literal so it can be converted to float.

```
val = values[3].split('\n')[0]
if res.get(date):
    res[date] += float(val)
else:
    res[date] = float(val)
```